# If Statement for attribute value is set to no

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, database, attribute-options, default-values

Just trying to write an if statement for this situation:
We do have some attributes which could have 3 values: empty space, yes and no.

The statement should require a yes value to display a jpg and if the no or empty is set display nothing or unset the jpg.

Now i am not sure about the syntax of that statement. What works so far is to display the jpg if the value exists in the first place.

So this is the syntax yet:

```
<?php $jpg= '<img src="jpg">'; ?>

<?php
if ($_product->getAn_55() != 0 && $_product->getAn_55() != ""):; ?>

<div class="new" style="border:0px solid #e2e2e2; float:right; padding-top:3px; padding-left:5px">
<?php echo ($jpg);?>
</div>

<?php endif?>
```

Now i was trying within the above sytanx like

```
<?php
elseif ($_product->getAn_55() == false ):; ?>
<?php unset ($jpg)

and 
<?php
elseif ($_product->getAn_55() == no ):; ?>
<?php unset ($jpg)
```

Which both doesn't work. So, whats the correct syntax for checking if a attribute has value set to yes or no?

I generally wonder, what value has to be set in the statement for text value or number value or MySQL Option Value and where to find it.

Would be nice, if anyone could give me some quick hint on this

Comment: What is you attribute code?

Answer (score 0):

you need to compare the strings using strcmp() like

```
if(strcmp($_product->getAn_55(),'false')==0)
```

then do your logic.
or try by giving ' ' to no and yes in your code.

Comment: unfortunately doesn´t work both. Do you maybe know where the options "no" value ID is stored in the MySQL Database?

Comment: i don't know that, but i think if the attribute is yes/no type then it is stored by 1 or 0 in the  database and you should check it by printing the value of $_product->getAn_55()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463580/how-does-product-attributes-and-attribute-options-are-stored-in-magento-database maybe this helps you